# Android change google map tile with custom tiles

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

Is it possible to change google map API v3 standart map to my own custom map coming from url? I know that OSMdroid provide it but i want work with google map API. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

it is indeed possible by using WMS services (if you don't know what they are, please google it).
Here is some code you can use:
The WMSTile provider is used by GoogleMapsAPI to set the map provider:

```
public abstract class WMSTileProvider extends UrlTileProvider {

// Web Mercator n/w corner of the map.
private static final double[] TILE_ORIGIN = { -20037508.34789244, 20037508.34789244 };
// array indexes for that data
private static final int ORIG_X = 0;
private static final int ORIG_Y = 1; // "

// Size of square world map in meters, using WebMerc projection.
private static final double MAP_SIZE = 20037508.34789244 * 2;

// array indexes for array to hold bounding boxes.
protected static final int MINX = 0;
protected static final int MAXX = 1;
protected static final int MINY = 2;
protected static final int MAXY = 3;

// cql filters
private String cqlString = "";

// Construct with tile size in pixels, normally 256, see parent class.
public WMSTileProvider(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected String getCql() {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(cqlString, Charset.defaultCharset().name());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return URLEncoder.encode(cqlString);
    }
}

public void setCql(String c) {
    cqlString = c;
}

// Return a web Mercator bounding box given tile x/y indexes and a zoom
// level.
protected double[] getBoundingBox(int x, int y, int zoom) {
    double tileSize = MAP_SIZE / Math.pow(2, zoom);
    double minx = TILE_ORIGIN[ORIG_X] + x * tileSize;
    double maxx = TILE_ORIGIN[ORIG_X] + (x + 1) * tileSize;
    double miny = TILE_ORIGIN[ORIG_Y] - (y + 1) * tileSize;
    double maxy = TILE_ORIGIN[ORIG_Y] - y * tileSize;

    double[] bbox = new double[4];
    bbox[MINX] = minx;
    bbox[MINY] = miny;
    bbox[MAXX] = maxx;
    bbox[MAXY] = maxy;

    return bbox;
}
}
```

And you can instantiate a custom one from your URL in such a way:

```
public static WMSTileProvider getWMSTileProviderByName(String layerName) {
        final String OSGEO_WMS = "http://YOURWMSSERVERURL?"
                + "LAYERS=" + layerName
                + "&FORMAT=image/png8&"
                + "PROJECTION=EPSG:3857&"
                + "TILEORIGIN=lon=-20037508.34,lat=-20037508.34&"
                + "TILESIZE=w=256,h=256"
                + "&MAXEXTENT=-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:3857"
                + "&BBOX=%f,%f,%f,%f&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256";

        return new WMSTileProvider(256, 256) {

            @Override
            public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
                final double[] bbox = getBoundingBox(x, y, zoom);
                String s = String.format(Locale.US, OSGEO_WMS, bbox[MINX], bbox[MINY], bbox[MAXX], bbox[MAXY]);
                try {
                    return new URL(s);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    throw new AssertionError(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Add to your map:

```
TileProvider tileProvider = getWMSTileProviderByName("MYLAYERNAME");
TileOverlay tileOverlay = myMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions()
    .tileProvider(tileProvider));
```

You should also set the map type to MAP_NONE when using a custom tile provider (if it is not transparent), so you avoid to load gmaps tiles that are hidden behind your custom map.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i have TMS server, not WMS, can i use this code? my URL like that format:

Comment: I don't know TMS, but from the url it seems it is using the same tiling scheme as google. So you just have to build the URL in the method: public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) 
using x,y,z of the url for x,y,zoom of the parameters. I'm not 100% sure because I don't know what TMS Server is.